# difference between eachLayer vs onEachFeature

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, qgis, folium

Could someone please explain me what is the difference betweennd`eachLayer` and `onEachFeature`. It's very confusing to me. I have read the leaflet documentation and it becomes more confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Leaflet `eachLayer` *method* applies to any Layer Group. It loops on the group child layers at the time it is called only.

The `onEachFeature` *option* applies to Leaflet GeoJSON Layer Group only. It executes on the group child layers after those are created, but note that the GeoJSON Layer Group can also receive more Features later on (through its `addData` method), leading to creation of more child layers, each going through the `onEachFeature` option again as well.